# comparing contents of 2 columns in 1 data frame and outputting row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in pandas and want to write a statement to compare `person-name` with `new-person` and print `identifier` , `person-name`, `new-identifier` , `new-person`

| identifier | person-name | type | name | new-identifier | new-person | new-type | new-name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (hockey, player) | sidney crosby | athlete | sidney | (pittsburg, player) | jane sidney | player | SC |
| (hockey, player) | sidney crosby | athlete | sidney | (pittsburg, player) | crosby sidney | player | MS |
| (hockey, player) | wayne gretzky | athlete | wayne | (oilers, player) | gretzky-wayne | player | WG |
| (hockey, player) | wayne gretzky | athlete | wayne | (oilers, player) | gretzky-wayne | player | TP |

Basically need to find sidney crosby and crosby sidney in the same data frame. I guess the logic would be if person-name = sidney crosby and new-person = crosby sidney, the output would be:

| identifier | person-name | new-identifier | new-person |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (hockey, player) | sidney crosby | (pittsburg, player) | crosby-sidney |

```
 df[person-name].equals(df[new-person])
```

wouldn't work since I'm comparing contents in the column rather than the entire column. How can I compare the contents of those 2 columns and print the 4 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one to way to do it

split the names and sort each of the two 'person-name' and 'new-person' and then compare the sorted names

```
df[
    df['person-name']
    .apply(lambda x:  ' '.join(sorted(x.split(' '))))
    .eq(
    df['new-person']
        .replace(r'-',' ',regex=True)
        .apply(lambda x:  ' '.join(sorted(x.split(' ')))))][
    ['identifier','person-name','new-identifier','new-person']
]
```

```
    identifier       person-name    new-identifier       new-person
1   (hockey, player) sidney crosby  (pittsburg, player)  crosby sidney
2   (hockey, player) wayne gretzky  (oilers, player)     gretzky-wayne
3   (hockey, player) wayne gretzky  (oilers, player)     gretzky-wayne
```

to keep only the unique, assign the result to another DF and then keep only non duplicated rows

```
df2=df[
    df['person-name']
    .apply(lambda x:  ' '.join(sorted(x.split(' '))))
    .eq(
    df['new-person']
        .replace(r'-',' ',regex=True)
        .apply(lambda x:  ' '.join(sorted(x.split(' ')))))][
    ['identifier','person-name','new-identifier','new-person']
]
df2[~df2.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

```
    identifier       person-name    new-identifier      new-person
1   (hockey, player) sidney crosby  (pittsburg, player) crosby sidney
2   (hockey, player) wayne gretzky  (oilers, player)    gretzky-wayne
```

Comment: do you know how I could have just the front row, I'm trying to understand how the comparison would work and if I could drop the rows using dp.drop or is there a better way?

Comment: @learner22, just added a second solution to keep only unique rows